# Initializing lots of constants to consecutive integers. C-like enum in Java?

Tags: java

I have to initialize about 10-12 constants to consecutive integers. I am doing this at the moment:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static final int A = 1;
    public static final int B = 2;
    public static final int C = 3;
    public static final int D = 4;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Just wondering if there's a neater way to do this. Maybe something like enum in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are enums in Java since 1.5. Or you could also do:

```
private static int x = 0;

public static final int A = x++;
public static final int B = x++;
public static final int C = x++;
public static final int D = x++;
.
.
```

Comment: I believe you declared `D` twice.

Comment: took the liberty of fixing it.

Answer (score 4):

The preferred way is to use an `enum`:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A, B, C, D;
    public final int value = ordinal() + 1; // or "+ base index"
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MyEnum.B.value); // 2
}
```

---

Or, if you really do prefer primitive integer constants, you could do:

```
public static final int A, B, C, D;
static {
    int x = 1;
    A = x++; B = x++; C = x++; D = x++;
}
```

This limits the scope of the auxiliary counter-variable (`x`).

Comment: Isn't that constructor the default one for values? Why implementing it?

Comment: @Gene Martin: No, the default constructor does not initialize any field called `value`. And btw, I cleaned up the answer and put the assignment at the declaration instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use enum in Java

```
enum MyEnum {
   NOT_USED, A, B C, D, E, F
}

MyEnum x = 
int num = x.ordinal();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an [enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).
Something like:

```
class MyClass
{
public enum myEnum {
   A, B, C,D 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums in java work diffently to enums in C.  You could do something like the following, but you'd then have to call getValue() each time you wanted to use the constant, which may not be quite what you're after.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A(1), B(2), C(3), D(4);

    private final int value;        

    private MyEnum(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```